# How to specify a particular optimization method in glm

Tags: r, optimization, glm

In the documentation for `glm`, there is a `method` option where in the documentation it says that

> User-supplied fitting functions can be supplied either as a function
> or a character string naming a function, with a function which takes
> the same arguments as glm.fit. If specified as a character string it
> is looked up from within the stats namespace.

I would like to use a binomial non-negative least squares optimizer so that the coefficients are non-negative and sum up to 1. An example of this optimizer being used is in the `SuperLearner` package with the option `method = "method.NNLS"`. Below is a reproducible example:

```
library(SuperLearner)
# binary outcome
set.seed(1)
N <- 200
X <- matrix(rnorm(N*10), N, 10)
X <- as.data.frame(X)
Y <- rbinom(N, 1, plogis(.2*X[, 1] + .1*X[, 2] - .2*X[, 3] +
                           .1*X[, 3]*X[, 4] - .2*abs(X[, 4])))

SL.library <- c("SL.glmnet", "SL.glm", "SL.knn", "SL.mean")

# least squares loss function
test.NNLS <- SuperLearner(Y = Y, X = X, SL.library = SL.library,
                          verbose = TRUE, method = "method.NNLS", family = binomial())
> test.NNLS

Call:  
SuperLearner(Y = Y, X = X, family = binomial(), SL.library = SL.library, method = "method.NNLS",  
    verbose = TRUE) 


                   Risk      Coef
SL.glmnet_All 0.2460486 0.0000000
SL.glm_All    0.2507033 0.2423697
SL.knn_All    0.2508500 0.3493301
SL.mean_All   0.2475494 0.4083002
```

Notice that the `Coef`s are non-negative and sum to 1. Is there a way to use the same optimizer with `glm`? Or a different optimizer that uses the same constraint? I've tried:

`glm(Y ~ as.matrix(X), family = "binomial", method = "method.NNLS")`

but it did not work.

Comment: glmnet in the glmnet package accepts bounds.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, can it add a constraint so that the coefficients sum to 1?

Comment: I'm working on this, but it's non-trivial. (1) The `nnls` optimizer itself only constrains the parameters to be non-negative. The `method.NNLS` code deals with the sum-to-1 constraint by simply dividing the coefficients by their sum to make sure they sum to 1.  This is **not the same** (AFAICT) as fitting the GLM with the constraint. Can you confirm that you're OK with this type of solution, or do you really want to fit the model with the parameters constrained to sum to 1?

Comment: (2) how committed are you to/how necessary is the SuperLearner optimizer and plugging in a method to `glm()`? In other words, would an alternative solution to solving the problem (fit a binomial GLM with the parameters constrained to be non-negative and sum to 1) solve your problem?

Comment: (1) I would like to fit the model with the parameters constrained to sum to 1 if possible (2) I'm not committed to the SuperLearner optimizer. The alternative solution would solve my problem.

Comment: there may be other questions on SO about fitting with this kind of constraint; I haven't looked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*A* way (not the only way, possibly not the most efficient or most compact) to solve this problem is to do general maximum-likelihood estimation on parameters in a transformed space; probably the most common such transformation is the *additive log ratio transformation* (e.g. as in `compositions::alr()`). This solution uses the `bbmle` package, which is a wrapper around `optim()`; in this case, it doesn't actually offer that much advantage over directly using `optim()`

```r
library(bbmle)
library(compositions)
linkfun <- function(mu) as.numeric(compositions::alr(mu))
invlink <- function(eta) as.numeric(compositions::alrInv(eta))

## negative log-likelihood function: first convert the parameter vector
## from the constrained (alr) space to the unconstrained space, then
## convert the linear predictor from an unconstrained space to the
## constrained (probability, (0,1)) space
lfun <- function(beta) {
    -sum(dbinom(Y, size=1, 
                prob = plogis(as.matrix(X) %*% invlink(beta)),
                log=TRUE))
}
npar <- ncol(X)
```

Using `mle2`:

```r
## extra setup for using mle2 with a score function that takes a vector
## parameter
pnm <- paste0("beta", seq(npar))
parnames(lfun) <- pnm
    
m1 <- mle2(lfun, start = setNames(rep(0, npar-1), pnm[-1]), vecpar = TRUE)
invlink(coef(m1))
##  [1] 4.897617e-01 2.221793e-01 1.274830e-05 2.198596e-05 7.541545e-02
##  [6] 1.175966e-01 1.590407e-05 4.662563e-02 4.825376e-02 1.170077e-04
```

or

```r
opt <- optim(par = rep(0, npar-1), fn = lfun, method = "BFGS")
invlink(opt$par)
```

#### note 1

My model fit doesn't match the method you used to generate the data (this would be coded in a formula as `~ 0 + x1 + x2 + x3 + x3:x4 + abs(x4)`), but neither does your `SuperLearner` example, so I didn't worry about it.

#### note 2

My guess (not carefully considered) is that the approach above will **not** give the same results as using `SuperLearner`; looking at the code, what `SuperLearner` does is to find a non-negative solution to the (weighted) least-squares problem, then transform the coefficients to the compositional space by dividing the coefficient vector by its sum. This is *not the same* as solving the minimum-deviance/maximum-likelihood problem with the parameters constrained to be non-negative and sum to 1. If you want the `SuperLearner` solution, it may indeed be possible to do it by passing an appropriate `method=` argument to `glm`, but I couldn't see how to do the constrained MLE solution with `glm`.